# Using CookieHandler with OkHttp and Retrofit 2

Tags: android, cookies, retrofit, okhttp

I am having troubles with OkHttp and Cookies management.

I am creating a Retrofit client with a custom OkHttpClient with a CookieManager.

```
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
mCookieHandler = new CookieManager();
okHttpClient.setCookieHandler(mCookieHandler);
final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
       .baseUrl("http://api.mysite.com/")
       .client(okHttpClient)
       .addConverter(String.class, new StringConverter())
       .build();
```

I have then an auth request that answer me an auth cookie if my login is good:

```
interface AuthService {
    @POST
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<String> auth(@Url String url,
                      @Field("login") String login,
                      @Field("password") String password);
}
```

Using it like this :

```
mAuthService = retrofit.create(AuthService.class);
mAuthService.auth("https://auth.mysite.com/some/path", "mylogin", "mypassword")
            .enqueue(new AuthCallback());
```

In the response headers of this request, I have one like this :

`Set-Cookie: auth=someauthkey468TYUIYTYUY; path=/; domain=.mysite.com`

After the request, if I look inside of the cookie handler, there is one entry in the map of the cookie store :

```
key = http://auth.mysite.com 
value = a list of cookie with only auth=someauthkey468TYUIYTYUY
```

At this point every thing is working good. My auth cookie is perfectly stored in the cookie handler.

But now, I want to perform a request to download some data with another service :

```
interface UserService {
    @GET("user") // remember that the base url of retrofit is http://api.mysite.com/
    Call<String> getMyCurrentInfo();
}

retrofit.create(UserService.class).getMyCurrentInfo().execute();
```

And here, I expected the OkHttp to add the previously received cookie stored in the cookie handler to this request but no header is added by OkHttp !
The cookie is never sent back to the server. :(

Is there something not working with Cookie handler and OkHttp or am I trying to do something impossible (unless adding the header manually) or am I just bad and failed somewhere ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you set up everything correctly.
There are some issues with CookieManager in Android.
I spent a lot of time trying to make it works. As result I implemented small custom implementation of cookies managment via interceptors.

You can read more about it:

[Do cookies in OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/991)

[Do cookies in OkHttp 2](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1061)

[AOSP issue 75182](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75182)

Also you could find many related post on SO

Comment: Well this is unfortunate. I will implement a custom interceptor that will add my cookies automatically ... Thank you

Comment: @pdegand59 or Ilya, can you post a small example of how to do that custom interceptor?

Comment: Had the same question as Jan, so here is the link is case someone comes searching: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors